# import dynamic pinia store and vue component based on a reference

Tags: vue.js, quasar, pinia

I'm developing an app with Quasa V2 framework, vue, vite, pinia, and  format. I got a basicList.vue component that get all its control attributes and properties from a pinia store called oTable. In my vue component I import the right pinia store and i get a full crud working for that table. Validations calls are pinia actions. Pinia store does every crud actions and calls to the backend.

I have almost 60 reference tables on my app. So, I want to reuse this basicTable
In order to do that, in my route list I added a prop with the table name and i read it in basicList .

If the user select "client" table from the menu. The router calls basicList.vue with "tableName" = "client" prop.

An I have to import the pinia store and the edition child component for the client table. I'm doing that this way:

```
import { tableStore } from "stores/tables/client.js";
const oTable = tableStore();

const editionComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
import("./ClientItem.vue")
);
```

This works fine, but i want to make this using the tableName prop instead to a literal string with the table name.

Something like this:

```
import { tableStore } from "stores/tables/${tableName}.js";
const oTable = tableStore();

const editionComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() =>
import("./${tableName}Item.vue")
);
```

Unfortunelly, this approach didn´t work. At this points, i don't know how to solve it. Because imports happend at the compile time, and tableName is available at the runtime.

I'll appriciate any help or walkaround on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a utility function that maps table names to their respective module paths and then use this map for dynamic imports. Here's an example:

```
const tableModuleMap = {
    'client': {
        store: 'stores/tables/client.js',
        component: './ClientItem.vue'
    },
    //... other tables
};

function getTableModule(tableName, type) {
    const path = tableModuleMap[tableName][type];
    if (!path) throw new Error('Unknown table name or module type');
    return import(path);
}

// Usage
let storeModule = await getTableModule(tableName, 'store');
const oTable = storeModule.tableStore();

const editionComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() => getTableModule(tableName, 'component'));
```

Note that these dynamic imports return promises, so make sure you're handling them correctly in the context of your Vue component (e.g., using `async` and `await` or `.then()`).